# Column not found in complex order by zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sql-order-by

. I cant run this simple code in zend . query has been worked directly in mysql whithout problem !

```
 SELECT * FROM `product` ORDER BY (

 CASE WHEN name LIKE '%برج خنک کن%' THEN 1 WHEN name LIKE '%برج خنک
 کننده%' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END )
```

but this code in zend shows me this error :

> exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' (case when name LIKE '%برج خنک کن%' then 1 when name LIKE '%برج خنک کننده%' then 2 else 3 end)' in 'order clause'' in

this is my code

```
$select = $products->select()->order(" (case 
            when name LIKE '%برج خنک کن%' then 1 
            when name LIKE '%برج خنک کننده%'  then 2 
            else 3 
        end)");
```

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70243/farsi-programming-discussion

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
$products->select()->order( 
    array(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("Your case")) 
);
```

Comment: I edited my answer. you must use the full name space if you don't add `use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;` at the top,

Comment: now my page shows nothing (compeltly white ) when i did this!

Comment: maybe it`s beacuse of old zend version!

Comment: Hmm. what version you use ? my sollution is for zf2

Comment: Copyright (c) 2005-2009 Zend Technologies USA Inc. 
version    $Id: Exception.php 16199 2009-06-21 18:42:43Z thomas $

Comment: that seams to be zf1. I have no clue how to do that in zf1. check the source files to see what order accepts and modify your title maybe someone else answer it.